# Use ARM template to create directories in Azure Storage Containers?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I can't seem to find documentation saying this can be done? But neither saying that this can't be done. So wondering if anyone else has had this idea/query in past.

I have ARM template to generate our new data lake and it's creating storage account and container. It'd have been great to create folder structure also using the template. Or maybe the directories don't count as a 'resource'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARM api does not support that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/blobcontainers/create

you can only work on containers\file shares\tables and queues. You cannot create object inside those. So its not possible with ARM Templates. They can only operate against ARM apis.

you can use deploymentScript resource as a workaround

Comment: Can you describe better your approach with the deployment script? I have a question which is similar to this and I am curious to know about this script. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69803750/how-to-create-a-folder-inside-of-an-azure-data-lake-container-using-an-arm-templ